# Replace Line but keep part of it in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I want to use Notepad++ to find/replace large chunks of code:

I have lots of:

angles[]={6.2744589,5.4066987,1.4066987};

with 3 values. I need to put all first and second values to 0 and keep the value in the third position :S

angles[]={6.2744589,5.4066987,1.4066987};

to

angles[]={0,0,1.4066987};

Thanks!

Comment: I think you will find that Notepad++ is a difficult way to do this.  Have you considered writing a program to scan the file and break it up into pieces then resequence them?  You can keep  this open in Notepad++, then also open a new tab with the output file so you have both.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I don't have time to test or write it but a regex that would replace anything between `{` and  the first `,` with `0` and also anything between two commas with `0` should do the trick based on your example.

Comment: @SDsolar "Notepad++ is a difficult way to do this" No it isn't.

Comment: You left out the part where I said "I think you will find..."  - speaking for myself, it is much easier to just write a quick program.  I can do some regex but that is more difficult for me than reading it in then writing it out in Python.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished with a regex (regular expression) search & replace in Notepad++.

Find: `angles\[\]={\d+\.\d+,\d+\.\d+,(\d+\.\d+)};`

Replace with: `angles[]={0,0,\1}`

Note that in the expression above we escape the brackets, hence the presence of the backslash (), the third group is a capture group (between parentheses). In the end we perform substitution for the first and second groups, and the third group is the original value (referred to as `\1`: the captured value).

I am attaching a screenshot sample.

[image: Notepad++ regex replace]

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\bangles\[\]=\{\K[^,]+,[^,]+`
- Replace with: `0,0`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          : word boundary, to be sure to match angles but not somethingangles
angles      : literally angles
\[\]=\{     : literally []=, brackets have to be escaped as they have special meaning in regex
\K          : Forget all we have seen until this point
[^,]+       : 1 or more any character that is not a comma, that matches also negative values
,           : a comma
[^,]+       : 1 or more any character that is not a comma
```

- *Check regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Result for given example:**

```
angles[]={0,0,1.4066987};
```